# Use 'alt' value to dynamically set 'title'

Tags: jquery, image, attr

I need some help, and before we get going, I know it is probably not best practice, but I am doing some maintenance to an existing site and need to accomplish the following for a fix.

```
<a rel="lightbox" href="site.com" title="a generated title">
    <img src="site.com/img" class="post-image" alt="a long description"/>
</a>
```

Okay, so I am trying to figure out how to use jQuery or any other method to take the `alt` attribute from my image, and dynamically overwrite the `title` attribute of my `a` tag.

Any help would be awesome, I am kinda lost at this juncture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $("a").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).find("img").attr("alt"));
   });
});
```

Comment: Sir, you are a scholar and a gentlemen. That seemed so obvious, not sure why I didn't see it. Nonetheless. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you didn't mention exactly which `<a>`s you wanted to change, so this would change all `<a>`s with an `<img>` inside...

```
$("a>img").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().attr("title", $(this).attr("alt"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
var a = $('a[rel=lightbox])');
var img = a.find('img');
a.attr('title', img.attr('alt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
});
```

Since jsFiddle.net seems to be flaky over the last day or so, you can see a demo at **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebevil/edit#javascript,html,live)**.

And if jsFiddle loads, a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vaX7b/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    var img = $(".post-image");
    if(img.length == 1) // meaning, at least one element was found
    {
        img.attr("title", img.attr("alt")); // pass the text in alt to title
        img.removeAttr("alt");              // remove alt
    }
});
```